# php -S localhost:8000 only working for files named as "index.php"

Tags: php, file, path, localhost

When i try different named file other than "index.php" it says "not found" and below "The requested resource / was not found on this server." this shows.

I need help.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a bit more detail. For example what was the name of the file and where exactly did you put it? Also, what URL did you use in your browser in order to try and view it? If I knew that it is possible I might be able to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.